# Is it possible to force enable the battery saver mode in Android Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, battery-life

It is possible to automatically enable battery saver mode in Android 5.0 when the battery hits 5 or 15%.

However sometimes it would be nice to enable this mode by hand. e.g. when the battery is still half full.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can actually make it automatic for any x% or as a shortcut for manual mode using automation apps. But I don't think you want it. The answers below should suffice.

Comment: This will be very helpful for those survival moments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can turn on the battery saver mode anytime.

Goto `Settings -> Battery -> Battery Saver -> On`

[image: Screenshot1]

You can easily turn off anytime by opening the notification and selecting

`TURN OFF BATTERY SAVER` option.

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: I don't have this On/Off switch: http://i.imgur.com/9UCT0ZT.png http://i.imgur.com/mgKMDNx.png (Lollipop Cyanogenmod)

Comment: Mine only lets me choose between 5%, 15%, or turning battery saver completely off. LG G4, Android 6.0