# Force "Battery Saver" mode in Android Lollipop Cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, settings, battery-life

Forcing "Battery Saver" mode [seems to be possible](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111112/is-it-possible-to-force-enable-the-battery-saver-mode-in-android-lollipop) via `Settings -> Battery -> Battery Saver -> On` using some Lollipop phones, but on my CyanogenMod 13.0-20150316 there is no such option:

[image]
[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is setting up  a **Custom battery saver**

According to [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/change-battery-saver-trigger-percent-start-when-screen-off/) source:

> The Battery Saver parameter is defined in the Settings.Global class,
>   although you won’t find the documentation on that page as the feature
>   is not guaranteed to be present on every device.
>
> However, a cursory glance at AOSP or by listing all of the available
>   settings on your device reveals that the Battery Saver parameter is
>   defined under the `low_power`  constant. It holds an integer value of
>   either `0` or `1` for “off” and “on” respectively. The trigger
>   level/percent value for Battery Saver is defined under the 
>   `low_power_trigger_level` constant, and this holds an integer value
>   between 1 and 100. By modifying either of these two parameters, we can
>   control Battery Saver ourselves.

Setting the custom battery trigger level  involves modifying the `low_power_trigger_level` constant itself to let the Android system handle enabling/disabling Battery Saver on its own.

Another requirement is [adb](/questions/tagged/adb), once setup execute:

```
adb shell settings put global low_power_trigger_level TRIGGER_LEVEL
```

where `TRIGGER_LEVEL` is the battery level (between 1-100%) that you want Android to enable Battery Saver.

Comment: Please provide feedback if any of the mentioned above works for you, if not I will be happy to send these solutions to trash :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tasker for this:

**Using Tasker Battery Saver Mode Task**

**Prerequisites:**

- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)
- [Power Toggles (plugin)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en)
- Root

In tasker, Create a task name it anything e.g **TaskerBatterySaverMode**.

A1: Task >> If {`%state` is not set}

*For actions to run when the toggle is turned on, use if condition `%state` is set.
For actions to run when the toggle is turned off, use if condition `%state` is not set*

Press back for second action

A2:  Code >> Run shell >> { command: `settings put global low_power 0` Tick  use root}

A3: Plugin >> Power toggles >> Modify PowerToggle state [Configuration: Set current toggle to off]

A4: Task >> Else

A5: Code >> Run shell >> { command: `settings put global low_power 1` Tick  use root}

A6: : Plugin >> Power toggles >> Modify PowerToggle state  [Configuration: Set current toggle to on]

A7: End if

**Explanation:**  When Tasker Battery Saver mode is toggled on using Power toggles, actions 5 and 6 are executed.  When toggled off, actions 2 and 3 are executed

You may create a profile to your liking e.g customising battery percentage levels.

**Important**: Enable external access (Go into Preferences in Tasker.  Under the Misc tab, check the “Allow External Access” box).

**Set up Power Toggles**

- Launch the Power Toggles app and select Notification.
- Turn on the notification shade widget by turning the toggle on in the top right corner.  You can then select Customize.
- On this screen, click the Add Toggle button.  Select the Custom tab and then click “Tasker toggle”
- Select your Tasker battery saver mode task (previously created task: TaskerBatterySaverMode).  Leave the type as “Single icon”.

Toggle your battery saver mode on and off with ease from notification bar!

Screenshot:

[image]

Credits

1. [[How To] Tasker Battery Saver Mode On Android Lollipop](http://tinsley.io/2015/03/tasker-battery-saver-mode-android-lollipop/)